# Is there a way to change the project from git to the state when I first checked out? (didn't make any commit)

Tags: eclipse, git

I imported a git project using "Clone URI" in Eclipse.

I made some changes on it. However, if I want to start from the original.

**Instead of disconnecting from a repository, deleting files and folders, and re-importing the project.**

**Is there a way to keep the project same as a project in Git?**

In this case, I don't know which terminology to use (revert, reset, rollback, re-checkout). Instead of importing a project again, I want to change my project to the time when I first checked out.  I don't need to commit changes I made.

I'm not trying to undo the commit, nor do I try to restore any deleted file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not commit any of the changes you made after cloning, you can just do `git checkout -- .`

This will get rid of all your changes, and put your project back in the state it was when you cloned it.

Comment: I did click "checkout" but it didn't change. so I though there must be some other way.

Comment: The checkout button in your IDE probably runs a different command than `git checkout -- .`, so try running that command from your shell instead

Comment: okay I'll try that.  Do I check out from local repository? or remote?

Comment: Your local repository. `cd` into your project folder, then run `git checkout -- .`